# Keyfob battery dead - Can I still start my 2007 Mini Cooper S

Tags: electrical, ignition, key, mini-cooper

I don’t drive it too much but noticed that when I put the keyfob in, and press start button it sort of acts like the car’s battery is dead but after a few attempts it will start. Today I couldn’t unlock my truck from my fob and realized my fob battery has gone dead. Could this have been the issue with the slow ignition start?

Thanks,
Nicole

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you put the FOB in the tray the car will still start and hopefully after some miles driving it will charge.  With the FOB battery discharged, none of the remote functions will work.

If it's dead when you put it in the tray it may take a few seconds to come to life and allow the car to unlock.